# Jupyter on VSCode - Jupyter notebook failed to launch

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to use vscode to write and manipulate my ipynbs.

I've successfully managed to run a jupyter server separately and link it to vscode, though, it appears to make imports kind of sketchy.. (`os.getcwd()`) returns the **workspaceFolder**, rather than the **FileDirname**, as is set in the extension settings ), so I decided to try to use the default setting (vscode automatically starts server).

Bottom line is, a cmd prompt is opened and the server is running, but vscode has trouble connecting to it and returns: 'Jupyter notebook failed to launch.

> Error: The Jupyter notebook server failed to launch in time'.

I'm able to connect to jupyter through browser even after the error message, it keeps running, but it looks pretty dodgy. Will add some images below.

[server running and message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZS5L0.png)

[dodgy jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zew3A.png)

Any ideas what could fix this issue?

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: Have you looked at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py?

Comment: @kubatucka, yes I did look at the walkthrough, but I read it again since you suggested. The problem is solved.. Feel kind of embarassed now. The issue was solved by selecting the interpreter for running jupyter server. Thank you.